# WordPress file manager plugin

Tags: plugins, file-manager

I would like to manage some files available for download from my WordPress page. Because the file should be attached to more pages I would like to define pages where file is avalable for file directly. I don't want define the same file for lot of pages in my application.

Do you know some plugin which should help me with this?

Comment: **SOLVED**

I solve this issue myself. I used `file-un-attach` plugin, which allows attach same file to more pages.

This plugin uses custom find method which finds by text in title and content. If you write "" (double quotes) into search box it will find all pages in application. Result set is limited to 50 rows - it is possible remove it in `file-un-attach/ajax.php`

Hope will help others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this issue myself. I used `file-un-attach` plugin, which allows attach same file to more pages. This plugin uses custom find method which finds by text in title and content. If you write `""` (double quotes) into search box it will find all pages in application. Result set is limited to 50 rows - it is possible remove it in `file-un-attach/ajax.php` Hope will help others.